# python 3 dictionary filter

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have the dictionary:

```
tmpDict = {
'original': ['Locate inner shroud bushes onto variable vanes.'], 
'operation': ['locate'], 
'target': ['inner shroud bushes'], 
'targetState': ['onto variable vanes'], 
'referenceToSpecification': [None], 
'relation': [None], 
'operationManner': [None], 
'aim': [None]
}
```

and I want to filter it as to erase the "None" values. Thus getting this:

```
{
'original': ['Locate inner shroud bushes onto variable vanes.'], 
'operation': ['locate'], 
'target': ['inner shroud bushes'], 
'targetState': ['onto variable vanes'], 
}
```

I have tried:

```
tempDict = {k: v for k, v in tempDict.items() if v != None}
```

and some more without any luck.

Answer (score 4):

Your values are `[None]` not `None`.  You should be testing for `[None]` instead:

```
tempDict = {k: v for k, v in tmpDict.items() if v != [None]}
```